# Ubuntu 18.04 wont open terminal after Python 3.7.4 install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I had Ubuntu 18.04 running, and then I ran the commands

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib nginx
sudo apt install python3.7-venv
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa
sudo apt install python3.7
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and set the default Python 3 version to Python 3.7.4. I rebooted the system and now the terminal won't open. I also have a small notification in the top right hand corner that says "error occurred while checking for updates".

How do I fix this? Is this because I deleted the repository from the PPA or is it due to having the default as Python 3.7.4? Should I have left the repository in the PPA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two Python version installed.

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Edit `#! /usr/bin/python3` to `#! /usr/bin/python3.6`

Maybe go to    `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` and set the Python 3.6 as default, or you may found problems with add ppas's, commands not found etc.

Comment: i have the same problem after installing python3.8-distutils. this one did the trick. thanks man!

Comment: I think i have the same problem, but I can't open terminal now, so how I run the command you have?

Comment: I had the same issue as @HaipengSu, that I wasn't able to open the terminal to fix the issue with the terminal. For some reason though if I went into task manager right-clicked on a folder and selected "open in terminal" this actually opened the terminal. At this point, I was able to make the change. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `xterm` 
   The standard terminal emulator for the X Window System in your OS, if it isn't, you can install it from Ubuntu software
2. Type `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
3. Choose "python3.6" as a default